# how do I make before_action :logged_in_user work with a modal and remote form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example if I have the following code:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in or register"
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

when a web user navigates to any of the photo routes: `example.com/photos`, `example.com/photos/new`, `example.com/photos/1` they will be `redirected_to` the `login_url` page if they were not already logged_in.

but what if I am opening up a modal from the homepage, `example.com` that contains a `remote` `form_for @photo?` it will not allow a web user who is not logged_in to submit the form, and upon submitting the form, they will then be `redirected_to` the `login_url` however this is far from ideal and I want them to be redirected immediately.

Comment: if using modals, then u gotta store in JS browsered.

Comment: are you following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorials?

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun yes, building upon it.  i am using his User authentication build instead of devise.

Comment: @7urkm3n do you mean like a `_application.js.erb` file because I will need to use erb code as well. I guess that would work. It is not possible to use `before_action` with a modal?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss So did you check the answer below?, Me too used Rails tutorials. And I used `logged_in?` in a similar situation.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss how yr opening Modal, ist after clicking to `photos/1` ?

Comment: @7urkm3n no i am opening the modal directly from the root_url

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss if user will not click on `photos/:id` then how you want to store the url ? i am miss understanding smth there...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i was just explaining how before_action works when I stated: `example.com/photos, example.com/photos/new, example.com/photos/1 they will be redirected_to the login_url page if they were not already logged_in`... basically I just have my homepage, and that opens a modal with a remote form for uploading photos:  `<%= simple_form_for :photo, :url => photos_path, html: {class: 'dropzone', id: 'dropform3'}, remote: true do |f| %>`... this redirects a user that is not `logged_in?` upon the submission of the form but I want them to be redirected immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views; I think you could put this remote form in a partial, Then render it if the user logged in, It should be something like that

homepage.html.erb

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%= render 'form_partial' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'somthing_else' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this is a possibility but I cannot use redirect_to in the view (I guess I could use javascript to do that) or put the login form into the modal.